# Powershell Error: Value does not fall within expected range .GetCollection("Components", [Application Key]

Tags: powershell, com+

I can run the code below succesfully, pasting line by line in the server Powershell ISE.

But when I run a .ps1 script I get a bunch of errors which I figure the first one is the important one: "Value does not fall within expected range." Which occurs when I try to fill a variable with the components of the application,  `$compColl = $appsColl.GetCollection("Components", $app.Key)`

Here is my code that doesn't work when inside a script. There is more code before to move and rename files and it all works.

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog

$appsColl = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")

$appsColl.Populate()


$targetApp = "pkgAdap2"
$app = $appsColl | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq  $targetApp}

*****************************************************************
 $compColl = $appsColl.GetCollection("Components", $app.Key)
*****************************************************************
$compColl.Populate()


$app.Value("IsEnabled") = $false
$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication($targetApp)


for ($i = $compColl.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; --$i)
{
  $compColl.Remove($i)
}

$compColl.SaveChanges()
```

Here is a successful attempt using same code, line by line in a Powershell ISE. No errors, successful completion of task:

```
PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> $app = $appsColl | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq  $targetApp}

PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> $compColl = $appsColl.GetCollection("Components", $app.Key)

PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> $compColl.Populate()

PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> $app.Value("IsEnabled") = $false

PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> $comAdmin.ShutdownApplication($targetApp)

PS C:\Users\jdavis_admin> for ($i = $compColl.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; --$i)
{
  $compColl.Remove($i)
}
```

I couldn't get any sleep loop to work, it's seems to error on the .GetCollection line in the script, but not when run line by line. So I put a break point right after .GetCollection to make sure and sure enough, that is the offending line. I have no idea what is going on or how to hack around this to delete the components.

```
#Get application to futz with:
$targetApp = "pkgAdap2"
$app = $appsColl | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq  $targetApp}

#GET Components in pkgAdap2
$compColl = $appsColl.GetCollection("Components",$app.Key)

Read-Host -Prompt "This is temporary stop and exit to see if .GetCollections finishes"
```

[image: Error display for .GetCollection line]

Comment: I'm guessing that the `Populate()` method returns to the prompt before completing. You may need to wait for it to finish with something like `Do{$LastCount = $appsColl.count;start-sleep -sec 2}While($LastCount -ne $appsColl.Count)` so after you tell it to populate it checks its item count, waits 2 second, and if the count has changed it waits again, until the count is the same after 2 seconds (hopefully indicating that it has completed populating its collection).

Comment: TheMadTechnician, you might have something there but I don't think the syntax is correct for the loop because now the script doesn't run at all which is usually what happens if I add something new. I will research how to sleep x amount but at the same time maybe you could make your comment an answer in case it is correct and then I can accept it as the answer. Cheers.

Comment: I added Start-Sleep -s 100 and it still had the error with "Value does not fall within expected range". It them  waited 100 seconds and all the other errors showed up. I can run the code on the server successfully, I can do a remote session from my workstation and run the code line by line successfully.

Comment: Have you considered running it locally and using the [Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678944(v=vs.85).aspx) method instead of running it through a remote session?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the C++ version in PowerShell. . . .The error is not very precious. What "Value" does not fall within the expected range? The name "Components"? The $app.Key? There are 91 components in the Application. Yet, it works line by line in PowerShell ISE by hand.

Comment: The ComObject you are using has a `Connect` method as well. just pipe `$comAdmin | Get-Member` and look at your available methods.

Comment: Still gives error if I include .Connect("") code as per documentation. Documentation also mentions that GetCollection will also work without using the .Connect("") method. Empty string is used to connect to local computer and since I am starting a remote session, then I my PS code is running local on the server. But I'm still trying to figure out what Value is falling out of expected range? I want to leave this discussion here because someone else might see an answer.

Comment: Thank you TheMadTechnician! You stuck with me and taught me some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have come to the realization that my .ps1 script is not running on the remote server after creating a remote session. The script creates the remote session but subsequent commands happen on the client PowerShell ISE that started the script. It runs on client it is sitting on and thus cannot instantiate the COM object by name because it doesn't exist. Hence "Value does not fall within expected range".

Commands work in PowerShell ISE on remote server. 
Commands work on client, line by line in client Powershell ISE because the remote session works for commands after it is started.

However, a script on client that starts a remote session, reverts right back to the client system.

So that answers my question that started this thread. I will have to create another thread for how to run a remote script or run cmdlets in remote session.

Ok, so I moved the COM+ replacement part of the script to it's own script residing on the server. Then I was able to call it from my 1st script(on client). It now works for what I want.

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "xxHSxxPLxx" -Credential $credential

Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command {D:\ServerDLLDev\RemoteCOMInstall.ps1}
```

I could have done this all from the 1st script on the client but the code would have been an eyesore because of the embedded scripts in the -Command syntax. I hope my troubles have helped someone else.